# Docker service container auto restart after specific time interval

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

We have a docker swarm and we normally run service container using Docker create service API. Now we are seeing after certain time interval the services are not responding ( means the application running inside container ). As of now the solution looks like restarting the service after specific time interval.And it worked when we tried it manually .

This is the `top` command output of `Host worker node`

[image]

And output of `docker stats`

[image]

Wanted to know what is the best approach to fix it. Also can we automate the solution.

Comment: Sounds like you need health check for your service.

Comment: Kubernetes will restart failed containers automatically 

Comment: Yes that docker swarm will do too. The problem is container is active but not responding (application inside container)

Comment: you can autmate this by two way 1st. Some health check if fail then restart the container. 2nd inside container a script that will ping the application port or route if not responding then restart the application or restart the container by killing root process in it. I can explain in answer if this make sens to you

Comment: @Adiii please can you explain the solution. I would definitely like to explore especially the 2nd option

Comment: okay let share your dockerfile. The entry point or CMD is important. I am seening that you are running java and python right? so  solution will be in python or bash but dockerfile is imp